# Unicode text in iOS label

Tags: ios, unicode

My iOS application is receiving unicode text from network, encapsulated in JSON. The text is in the following format `\u00d5\u00a1\u00d5\u00bd\u00d5`. How can I convert it to Unicode string which can be assigned to label in iOS?

Comment: Try
    `label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\u00d5"]`
This should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
NSString *labelString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:@"\U0001F50A"]; 

myLabel.text = labelString;
```